# Make my struct or class compatible with std::round

Tags: c++, math, rounding

Given the following, how do I make my class or structure compatible with *std::round*? (and I assume the same thing will make it usable with *std::floor* and *std::ceil* too).  Can I do this?

[C++ Shell version](http://cpp.sh/6n27)

```
#include <cmath>

struct Rectangle
{
    Rectangle(double _x1, double _x2, double _y1, double _y2) : 

        x1(_x1), y1(_y1), x2(_x2), y2(_y2) 

    {

    }

    double x1, y1, x2, y2;
};

int main(void )
{
    auto r = Rectangle(10.3, 10.4, 10.5, 10.6);

    r = std::round(r);

    std::cout << r.x1 << "," << r.y1 << "," << r.x2 << "," << r.y2 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What do you want `round` to do?  Should it sound all points?

Comment: You can write a method `round(Rectangle&)` put inside the namespace `std`, but it is strongly not advised.

Comment: @Bentoy13 adding to the `std` namespace is undefined behavior

Comment: @Kevin I thought it was tolerated. Thanks for the precision. It enforces my comment into "simply don't do it".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make [`std::round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) do this: it's already defined, and you can't add new overloads into namespace `std`.

What you *can* do is write a new function and use that instead (either a simple function or a method as Tartan Llama shows, but I'd prefer a free function here)

```
Rectangle round(Rectangle const &original) {
    return { std::round(original.x1), std::round(original.y1),
             std::round(original.x2), std::round(original.y2) };
}
```

Again, adding this to namespace std is illegal. Just make sure it's in the same namespace as `Rectangle` itself, and ADL will find it for you.

---

As an aside - having your constructor arguments and the members they correspond to ordered differently is confusing and error-prone here. Switching between uniform initialization and the explicit constructor above requires changing the parameter order, but there's no way for the compiler to spot this.

Comment: It not being possible to overload `std::round` is a much better reason than the other answer (although I note that it's usually possible to provide specialisations to templated `std::` functions, but `std::round` isn't one of those)

Comment: I'm not sure the `std::round(Integral)` overloads are required to be templates (they could just be an exhaustive set of overloads). If there's no template, you can't specialise it - even assuming specialisation of something in `std` were allowed

Comment: @Useless they are required to be function overloads, not templates.

Comment: Thanks, so that restricts us to one illegal mechanism that definitely can't be used with `std::round`. Looks like cppreference is misleading on that point.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking more in terms of genericity.  For example I have an Easing class that eases a value X from A to B.  It's templated so I can pass scalar types in (float, double) but because I have overloads for arithmetic operators on rectangle I can ease one rect to another.  I assumed functions like round, ceil and floor did the same kind of thing.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a function to round all the points of your `Rectangle` and return a new one then write it yourself; trying to use `std::round` for this doesn't really make sense.

One option:

```
struct Rectangle
{
    Rectangle(double _x1, double _x2, double _y1, double _y2) : 
      x1(_x1), y1(_y1), x2(_x2), y2(_y2) 
    { }

    Rectangle round() {
        return { std::round(x1), std::round(x2), 
                 std::round(y1), std::round(y2) };   
    }

    double x1, y1, x2, y2;
};
```

Then just call it like so:

```
r = r.round();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with you that it doesn't really "make sense" - the only difference between what you've written and what the OP asked for is that you didn't specialise `std::round()` but the semantics are otherwise identical.

Comment: You mean apart from not injecting it into the std namespace, not being a free function, and not specialising anything?

Comment: @Alnitak I'm not sure what you mean. `std::round` is not a template function, so you can't specialise it. And you can't overload it in the `std` namespace because that would be undefined behaviour.

Comment: @TartanLlama if you had pointed out (per the other answer) that it's actually not _possible_ to overload `std::round` that would have been fine.

Comment: Since your `round()` member function returns a copy and leaves the original untouched, it should be `const`. (And personally, I would prefer a name like `rounded` which sounds more intuitive as it returns a "rounded copy".)

Answer (score 1):

For discussion and thought:

My initial thinking was to provide an answer along the lines of @Useless:- A free function in the same namespace as the argument is the right way to do this.

However, thinking more carefully about the inferred semantics of the function `round` raised a question for me:

`round` sounds more like a command than a modifier. I know there is already a std::round that returns a copy of an integral argument, but then there is also a `std::sort` which sorts an object in place.

It seems to me that if you want a rounded copy, you might want to call a function called `rounded` and if you wanted to actually cause an object to round itself you might want to call `round` on it.

If you agree with this thinking, the code would start to look like this:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

struct Rectangle
{
    Rectangle(double _x1, double _x2, double _y1, double _y2) 
    : x1(_x1), y1(_y1), x2(_x2), y2(_y2) 
    {
    }

    Rectangle& round() {
      using std::round;
      x1 = round(x1);
      y1 = round(y1);
      x2 = round(x2);
      y2 = round(y2);
      return *this;
    }

  Rectangle& normalise()
  {
    // something here
    return *this;
  }

    double x1, y1, x2, y2;
};

Rectangle rounded(Rectangle r)
{
  return r.round();
}

Rectangle& round(Rectangle& r)
{
  return r.round();
}

Rectangle normalised(Rectangle r)
{
  return r.normalise();
}

Rectangle& normalise(Rectangle& r)
{
  return r.normalise();
}

int main(void )
{
    auto r = Rectangle(10.3, 10.4, 10.5, 10.6);

  // take a rounded, normalised copy
  auto r1 = rounded(normalised(r));
  // take a rounded copy
  auto r2 = rounded(r);

  // take a copy
  auto r3 = r;

  // normalise and round the copy
  normalise(round(r3));

  round(r);

  std::cout << r.x1 << "," << r.y1 << "," << r.x2 << "," << r.y2 << std::endl;
}
```